# Using jQuery to change HTML text input to password input

Tags: jquery, html, text, input, passwords

I have a text input which has a default value "password".

When the user clicks this field, i.e. when the focus is set to this textfield, I would like to change the input type to password..

I have tried this using jQuery, but no joy:

```
$("#passwordtxt").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($("#passwordtxt").val() == "Password"){    
      $("#passwordtxt").val("");      
    }
    $("#passwordtxt").attr('type','password');
});
```

Here is the HTML it applies to:

```
<form name = "loginform" action = "get_login.php" method = "post">
   <input id = "emailtxt" name = "username" type="text" size="25" value = "E-mail"/>
   <input id = "passwordtxt" name = "password" type="text" size="25" value = "Password"/>                                    
</form>
```

RESULT: It doesn't change the type to password, it just stays as text...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better solution would be to use the [`placeholder`](http://www.beyondstandards.com/archives/input-placeholders/) property which will achieve exactly what you want without fussing over changing the type of the input box.

otherwise you will want to address the property as a property and not as a attribute using:

```
.prop("type", "password");
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the HTML5 placeholder attribute, which can achieve this effect.

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

You may have to look into fallbacks if you want to support old IE, though.

Answer (score 2):

That's not directly possible. jQuery even has its own built-in error message for that:

```
jQuery.error( "type property can't be changed" );
```

Instead, you could have another element (password one) with the exact same position and size. The input is visible, whereas the password is initially not. Then, you can toggle between them:

```
$('#input, #password').toggle();
```

Make sure to focus the password one though.

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/mqq4z/

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the `type` of an `input` element with jQuery. The reason is that it's not possible in Internet Explorer, so jQuery prevents you from doing it in any browser (as it's meant to improve cross browser compatibility and all that).

Have a look at the [`.attr()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> **Note:** jQuery prohibits changing the type attribute on an  or
>    element and will throw an error in all browsers. This is
>   because the type attribute cannot be changed in Internet Explorer.

One potential solution to your problem could be to overlay the text (in a `span` or a `div` or whatever you like really) onto a `type="password"` input, and hide the text on `focus`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute) `placeholder` attribute will accomplish this. For example:

```
<input type = "password" placeholder = "Password" />
```

A javascript / jQuery solution will be needed to support clients not supporting HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you should use `placeholder` and plugins to get it to work in IE. That being said, if you still want to change the type of an `input` and don't need to support IE, you can do it using the [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method in jQuery:

```
$("#passwordtxt").prop("type", "password");
```